# Изменить фоновое изображение Python Moviepy

Tags: python

Есть видео .mp4 и картинка в произвольном формате.
Как заменить все кадры видео на данную картинку, причем с сохранением аудиоряда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже проверил - работает:

```
vi = VideoFileClip('видео.mp4')

im = ImageClip('картинка.jpg', duration=vi.duration)
im = im.resize(vi.size)
im = im.set_audio(vi.audio)

im.write_videofile("результат.mp4",fps=1, codec='libx264')
```